# Is it possible to hatch format railroads in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, style

Within mapbox tilemill it is possible to make make rail-roads like this:
[image: mapbox railroad example]
<sub>(source: [mapbox.com](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/assets/pages/styling-lines-9.png))</sub>

To achieve this you need to write the following code: [Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20160804043852/https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/styling-lines/)

```
#railroads {
  ::line, ::hatch { line-color: #777; }
  ::line { line-width:1; }
  ::hatch {
    line-width: 4;
    line-dasharray: 1, 24;
  }
}
```

Would it also be possible to achieve the same within leaflet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following library would allow you to achieve this on a leaflet polyline using text elements:
https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.TextPath

A working example can be found here: http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.TextPath/